# Regexp to match everything between # and punction characters

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I need to extract everything between a `#` and a space or any punctation character ( `.,;:_-`)
This is what I have so far.

```
var str = "#hello. foo bar"
var filter:RegExp = /#(.*?)(!.,?;:_-)/g;
var matches:Object = filter.exec(str);

if(matches != null){
trace("Found: "+matches[1])
} else {
trace("nothing found")  
}
```

It only works if the word is #hello! - I guess this part `(!.,?;:_-)` is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xC8lH9/2)

This example will be taking advantage of the `[^]` character group, this will match any character that is not in the group.  This allows you to simply say any not-in-list character.

```
#([^[\., -\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/zKb-g6MDNcxfNMfx)

---

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8L28r4t/1/)

```
var str = "#hello. foo bar";
var filter = RegExp = /#([^[\., -\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]+)/g;
var matches = Object = filter.exec(str);

if (matches !== null) {
    console.log("Found: " + matches[1]);
} else {
    console.log("nothing found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#(.*?)[!.,?;:_-]
```

What you need is `character class` `[]`.

`[!.,?;:_-] match a single character present in the list below`

```
     `!.,?;:_- a single character in the list !.,?;:_- literally`
```